# Running a script in PowerBroker

Tags: bash, shell, aix

I'm trying to script my commands that are run inside the pbrun shell. I've tried executing through a normal script, but that doesn't work because, to my understanding, pbrun is executed in its won subshell, making it hard, if not impossible, to pass commands to.

The only solution I'm thinking might work is that if I have a input/output text processor that listens to the terminal and responds accordingly.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/656801/80864

Answer (score 1):

I was able to send commands to the standard input of pbrun:

```
echo 'echo $HOSTNAME' | pbrun bash
```